# Why use 2 pointers to point to register address in atmega microcontroller?

Tags: c, pointers, avr, atmega, avr-gcc

This Line defines address for DDRD register in avr microcontroller

```
#define myDDRD *((volatile unsigned char* const) 0x31)
```

Can you please clarify how pointers is used in the above line?
Why do we need the first asterisk? shouldn't the second one be enough to point to the address 0x31?

Comment: it is a `const` pointer to a `volatile unsigned char` . If you just need help with reading it.

Comment: The asterisk `*` can mean different things in different scopes. It can mean multiplication if used as a binary operator. It can mean pointer is used in a type (like the typecast `(volatile unsigned char* const)`). Or it can mean *dereference a pointer* if used as an unary operator (which is what's happening here with the "first" asterisk).

Comment: @user247954 it's an external resource. But someone already did the work for you.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I get that but shouldn't the second asterisk be enough to define this pointer? why do we need 2 asterisks?

Comment: It's not defining the macro as an address. That macro is replaced in code by an lvalue.

Comment: @user247954 the outer most * is just to dereference this address. Basically it reads a single `BYTE` from the address `0x31`, everywhere this macro is used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can separate `*((volatile unsigned char* const) 0x31)` into 2 parts:
one inner part: `(volatile unsigned char* const) 0x31`
and one outer part: `*( inner part )`.

The **inner part** casts the integer `0x31` to a `volatile unsigned char` pointer which is constant.
A pointer type consist of the type name and an asterisk after the type name: `type*`. To cast an expression parenthesis are uses `(type)expression`.

The **outer part** dereferences the address the pointer contains as the asterisk is in front of it: `*pointer` in order to access it's value.

> If we take the inner part only why it isn't enough to read and write from the address?

Imagine a pointer `int* intPtr` pointing to a valid integer already. If you now want to change that integer you have to do it by `*intPtr = 42;`. If you would do instead `intPtr = 42;` you would write 42 to the pointers value and not to the address it points to, so that 42 would be the new address the pointer contains.

**In short:**
The macro reads one byte (`unsigned char`) from address `0x31` if it's on the right hand side of an assigment and writes one byte to it if it's on the left hand side.

**Usage:**
A typical usage is to do bit manipulation like clearing or setting single bits on that register lying on that specific address:

```
myDDRD &= ~(1 << PD0); /* clear bit 0 as PD0 is defined as 0 */
myDDRD |= (1 << PD1);  /* set bit 1 as PD1 is defined as 1   */
```

For more information about bit manipulation, see here: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990/8051589)

Comment: It can be used to *write* to the address as well, if used as the lhs of an assignment.

Comment: If we take the inner part only why it isn't enough to read and write from the address?

Comment: @user247954: Because it's just the pointer poiting to an address. To get access to that specific address you have to dereference it. If you have for example a `int* intPtr` and would use it by `intPtr = 42` you would write 42 to the pointers value and not to the address which the pointer contains.

Comment: @AndreKampling Ok I got it. Thank you for the clear explanation.